# custom plugin not visible to some user roles

Tags: user-roles, permissions

My plugin have minimum configuration like below.I can see plugin via WP admin under woocommerce main menu.but cannot see plugin from different role.That role can see woocommerce submenu.Only my custom submenu link not visible.

If i directly visit plugin link (domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=report-with-invoice) it says "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page."

```
<?php
 /*
  Plugin Name:Custom order reports
  Plugin URI:
  description:Order reports with invoice number
  Version: 1
  Author: myname
  Author URI: https://www.domain.com
  License: GPL2
 */
  
  add_action('admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu');
  function my_admin_menu() {
  add_submenu_page( 'woocommerce', 'Custom Report', 'Custom Report', 'manage_options', 'report-with-invoice', 'report_with_invoice' ); 
  }
    function report_with_invoice(){
 //my code goes here..
      }
?>
```

Anyone can help me please. I changed file permission to 775 through FTP. still give same error.

Comment: Your code explicitly says that only users with `manage_options` should see it…

Comment: What are the roles hat you want to be able to see it?

Comment: @PaulG. shop manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In place of `manage_options` use the following permission instead: `manage_woocommerce`:

```php
add_submenu_page( 'woocommerce', 'Custom Report', 'Custom Report', 'manage_woocommerce', 'report-with-invoice', 'report_with_invoice' );
```